# Unity programming C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Cannot figure out what I should do for the following error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

I am someone new to programming, if anyone can help me it will be greatly appreciated
Thank you very much

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShootingExample : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject projectile;
    public Transform spawnPoint;
    public SoundObject fightSound = new SoundObject();
    public SoundObject hitSound = new SoundObject();
    public Transform gun;
    public Transform ammo;
    public bool calculationDamage = false; //2011-05-26
    private Transform myTargetPoint;    //2011-05-26
    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        fightSound.gameObject = gameObject;
        fightSound.Init();
        hitSound.gameObject = gameObject;
        hitSound.Init();

        //2011-05-26 -B
        if (GetComponentInChildren<TargetPointBehaviour>() != null)
        {
            TargetPointBehaviour tpScript = GetComponentInChildren<TargetPointBehaviour>();
            myTargetPoint = tpScript.gameObject.transform;
        }
        //2011-05-26 -E
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //2011-05-26 -B
        //if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        //{
        //    StartCoroutine(Shoot());
        //}

        if (calculationDamage)
        {
            gun.gameObject.SetActive = false;
            ammo.gameObject.SetActive = false;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                StartCoroutine(Hit());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gun.gameObject.SetActive = true;
            ammo.gameObject.SetActive = true;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                StartCoroutine(Shoot());
            }
        }
        //2011-05-26 -E

    }

    IEnumerator Shoot()
    {
        GameObject proj;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        proj = (GameObject)Instantiate(projectile, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
        fightSound.Play();
        proj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * 1000); 
    }

    //2011-05-26 -B
    IEnumerator Hit()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);       
        hitSound.Play();

        if (Physics.Raycast(myTargetPoint.position, myTargetPoint.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, 1.5f))
        {
            hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", 10, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);           
        }       
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(40);
        calculationDamage = GUILayout.Toggle(calculationDamage, "Beating (Calculation Damage)");        

    }
    //2011-05-26 -E

}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: Consider being more specific in your title.

Comment: Error is exactly what it says. Go to the line in question and fix it - almost none of the posted code is even relevant.

Comment: its lines 40, 41, 49, 50 and I dont understand what I should fix

Comment: @brownmamba71- You need to give more information about which library you are using? I guess you are referring to "unturned.rocket.foundation 4.2.0.1" Because there are number of unity framework available. Also mention for which line you are getting error.

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 lines like this:

```
gun.gameObject.SetActive = false;
```

You're trying to assign the value `false` to it. As the error says, you can only do that if it's a property (or a variable or indexer). `SetActive` is a method that takes a parameter, like this:

```
gun.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

The imperative "SetActive" is a clue that it's a method. A property would usually be called "IsActive" or just "Active".